# Bulk Import of CSV into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am having a .CSV file that contain more than 1,00,000 rows.

I have tried the following method to Import the CSV into table "Root"

```
BULK INSERT  [dbo].[Root] 
FROM 'C:\Original.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But there are so many errors like check your Terminators.

I opened the CSV with Notepad.

There is no Terminator `,` or `\n`. I find at end of the row a square box is there.

please help me to import this CSV into table.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx

Comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server bulk-import operations. However, in some cases, a CSV file can be used as the data file for a bulk import of data into SQL Server. Note that the field terminator of a CSV file does not have to be a comma. To be usable as a data file for bulk import, a CSV file must comply with the following restrictions:

- Data fields never contain the field terminator.
- Either none or all of the values in a data field are enclosed in quotation marks ("").

Note: There may be other unseen characters that need to be stripped from the source file.  VIM (command ":set list") or Notepad++(View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters) are two methods to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with Java, I have written a set of tools for CSV manipulation, including an importer and exporter. The project is up on Github.com:

https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools

The importer is here:

https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools/tree/master/csv-db-importer

For instructions on how to use the importer, check:

https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools/blob/master/csv-db-importer/USAGE

You will need to make a simple mapping file. An example can be seen here:

https://github.com/carlspring/csv-db-tools/blob/master/csv-db-importer/src/test/resources/configuration-large.xml